# Is it possible to derive currency symbol from currency code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, currency

My iPhone app formats an NSDecimalNumber as a currency using setCurrencyCode, however another screen displays just the currency symbol. Rather than storing both the currency code and symbol, is it possible to derive the symbol from the code? I thought the following might work, but it just returns the symbol as $:

```
currencyCode = [dictPrices valueForKey:@"currencyCode"];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSString *currencySymbol = [numberFormatter currencySymbol];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be setting the locale, not the currency code. Then you will get the expected results from the formatters properties (or tweak them). You can also get things like the currency symbol from the locale object itself. So, for example, if you were displaying a number formatted for Japan in JPY:

```
NSLocale* japanese_japan = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ja_JP"] autorelease];
NSNumberFormatter *fmtr = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[fmtr setLocale:japanese_japan];
```

Now your number formatter should give you the correct symbols for currency symbol and format according to the rules in the specified locale.

Answer (score 6):

You can get number with currency symbol from number with currency code.

This is the way I do:

```
    NSString *currencyCode = @"HKD";
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    cell.amountLabel.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber: expense.exAmount];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return only the currencySymbol for a given currencyCode

```
- (NSString*)getCurrencySymbolFromCurrencyCode:(NSString*)currencyCode {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    [formatter release];
    return [string substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` has a `currencySymbol` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do it this way. If you decide to do it as SveinnV said it may be that the symbol is place before the `0` amount and then you are just getting `@"0"` as the symbol:

```
- (NSString *) currencySymbolForCurrencyCode:(NSString *) currencyCode
{

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

    [formatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];

    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];

    return [components firstObject];
}
```

Comment: Not only can the symbol be before of after the digit, there can be a space before or after the symbol, so it's better to prune both whitespace and digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

NSString * localeIde = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleCurrencyCode: currencyCode}];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIde];

NSString * symbol = formatter.currencySymbol;
```