# Display currency symbols using currency codes in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, currency, symbols, nslocale

Actually, I want to display the currency symbols of all currency codes and I'm using code like this,but i only get "$" symbols

```
-(void) showCurrenciesList
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];                         
    [numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    //[numFormatter setLocale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSMutableArray *aryAllCurrencies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    //NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"] autorelease];

    NSArray *currencyArray = [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]; 
    NSLog(@"Currency array : %@",currencyArray);

    for (NSString *currencyCode in currencyArray) 
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [numFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
        NSString *currencySymbol = [numFormatter currencySymbol];
        [aryAllCurrencies addObject:currencySymbol];
        [pool release];     
    }   
    //[countriesArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"currencies array : %@",aryAllCurrencies);   
}
```

Is this right or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574191/is-is-possible-to-derive-currency-symbol-from-currency-code

Comment: This method will show only current locales currency symbol.

Comment: are you sure the problem is there? I have just tested this out on my iphone simulator and on my mac os. displayNameString seems to be ok.

Comment: Thanks,I'm getting it.Actually I want to display the symbols of all currencies.So How can i show ? I have array NSArray *currencyArray = [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];

Comment: @konstantin : I have the problem in same line..bt I got that using NumberFormatter I can display..But if i write code like this then it displays only $..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From cocoa manual:  `Typically, therefore, you should use drain instead of release`. Actually you do not need a `NSAutoreleasePool` here at all. But it is not a reason of your problem. The problem is in locale. `NSNumberFormatter` has an assigned locale. If you do want to use `NSNumberFormatter` you should change your locale before sending `currencySymbol` message.
But I advice you to use `NSLocale` as you did in your first code:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"];
NSString *dollar = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:@"USD"];
[locale release];
```

I've checked this code twice before posting.

Comment: I want to display for all the currencies. Is there dynamic and fast way to set the locale instead of setting for each country?

Answer (score 4):

It's a straight high cost solution

```
+(NSString *)getCurrencySybolByCurrecyCode:(NSString *)code
{
    NSArray *locales = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
    for (NSString *currentLocale in locales)
    {
        NSLocale *currentLoc = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currentLocale] autorelease];
        if([[currentLoc objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode] isEqualToString:code])
        {
            NSLog(@"find symbol for code = %@ %@", [currentLoc objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode], [currentLoc objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]);
            return [currentLoc objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```