# Formatting long numbers (float) with thousand separator and 2 decimal

Tags: objective-c

> ```
> self.numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
> [self.numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
> [self.numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
> [self.numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
> ```

```
//In DataManager sharedClass .h 
- (void)setupCapital:(float)Capital;
- (float)readCapital;
(NSString*)formatCapital:(NSNumber *)Capital;

// In DataManager sharedClass .m
@property (assign, nonatomic) float theCapital;
- (NSString *) formatCapital:(NSNumber *)Capital {
return [self.numberFormatter stringFromNumber:Capital];
}

- (void)formatCapital:(float)Capital {
self.theCapital = Capital;
}

- (float) readCapital {
return self.theCapital;
}

// write the number
 float numberDecimal = [[DataManager sharedClass] readCapital];
self.labelCapital.text = [[DataManager sharedClass] formatCapital:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:numberDecimal]];
```

Why if i insert 123456,89 i correctly have in labelCapital the value 123.456,89

If i insert 1234567,89 i have instead in labelCapital 1.234.567,88

If i insert 123456789,89 i have instead in labelCapital 123.456.792,00

Any hints ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved using that code:

```
self.numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[self.numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[self.numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[self.numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[self.numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[self.numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

and changing float into double

i've also added last line to have results with only 2 decimal numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can have single function like this for converting a string variable into currency format:

```
  - (NSString *)convertToCommaSeparated:(NSString *)inputAmount{
    NSDecimalNumber *someAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:inputAmount];
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:@"USD"];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setFormat:@"#,##0.00"];
    return [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];
}
```

Note: The input should not have comma(,). You should remove comma's before passing to this function.

Comment: [self.numberFormatter setFormat : @"#,##0.00"]; not works, why ? More: i need to use EUR or ITA for italian currencyCode ?

Comment: found it instead of setFormat need to use now setPositiveFormat  [self.numberFormatter setPositiveFormat: @"#,##0.00"];  but the results continue to be inconsistent: if i insert 123456789,89 i obtain  123.456.792,00: why ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279124/display-currency-symbols-using-currency-codes-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits: